# How to raise custom error message via a django signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a model

```
class myModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   nums = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to save numbers in the `nums` field. But, no two instances of `myModel` that have same `type`can have same numbers (intersection of `nums` fields should be null).

I have tried writing a signal for it

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender = myModel)
def check_duplicate_nums(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   all_records = myModel.objects.filter(type = instance.type)
   for record in all_records:
      common_nums = list(set(record.nums).intersection(instance.nums))
      if len(common_nums) != 0:
         raise Exception("nums "+str(common_nums)+ " are repeated in " +str(record.name)+ " and "+instance.name)
```

But doing this opens the debug window of django admin. I want the error to be displayed right there. For example, when we save a model with an empty field and it throws an error saying 'This field is required' in red-highlighted line. I need to to display the error in that manner. Please suggest a way.

Thanks!

Comment: use `form` validations

Answer (score 0):

As @AnjaneyuluBatta said in comment you can move this kind of validation to the form. See [Adding custom validation to the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) documentation. Your `admin.py` should look like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel

    def clean_nums(self):
        # do something that validates your data
        nums = self.cleaned_data["nums"]
        all_records = myModel.objects.filter(type = instance.type)
        for record in all_records:
            common_nums = list(set(record.nums).intersection(instance.nums))
            if len(common_nums) != 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("nums "+str(common_nums)+ " are repeated in " +str(record.name)+ " and "+instance.name)
        return nums

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyAdmin)
```